# не могу правильно настроить права для Laravel

Tags: linux, nginx, laravel

laravel.log could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
[ошибка](http://pastebin.com/xr4HECJ8)

```
jashka#: ll
итого 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jashka jashka 0 ноя  1 10:25 laravel.log
```

Группа от которой запускается проект

```
Array ( [name] => nginx [passwd] => x [members] => Array ( ) [gid] => 982 )
```

Comment: А зачем вы храните логи в `/usr/share/...`? Для логов отлично подходит `/var/log`

Comment: Это не я храню, а фреймворе

Comment: Ну так настройте его https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#logging

Comment: А права на запись вам нужны для папки `/usr/share/nginx/html/wall/storage/logs/`